# what is the purpose of CDT in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse-cdt

hi now i am download and install ndk but the CDT is important for me...tell me the purpose CDT....

Comment: First hit in google: http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/

Comment: If you don't know CDT purpose, why do you think that it is important for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CDT is for developers who want to do C and C++ development in Eclipse, it's the C/C++ developer tools (see [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#What_is_the_CDT.3F)).

Since Eclipse was primarily built for Java originally (yes, I know its original *intent* was always to be a generalised environment, but Java really is the "elephant in the room" in terms of what Eclipse does), the CDT is sort of an add-on that allows it to interface to C compilers and other tools.

Answer (score 0):

providing a fully functional c and c++.Integrated development environment for eclipse platform